# How to initialize tm struct memebers in initializer list of a structure in C++ 98 standard

Tags: c++, struct, initializer-list, c++98

I'm trying to initialize ::tm struct's members in a structure using initializer list as shown below. But it's only possible in C++ stds > 98.

How can I achieve the same in C++ 98?

```
struct abc {
    abc () : time_struct_{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, x(0) { }
    ::tm time_struct_ ;
    int x;
};
```

Comment: Should't `time_struct_()` zero-initialize all its members?

Comment: @DanielLangr, It does initialize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Daniel Langr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580083/daniel-langr) mentioned `time_struct_()` does the job.

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than a direct answer to the question. You can consider adding this as a comment next time instead of posting it as an answer.